# pytest parametrize run one more test than I set the parameter group

Tags: pytest

Here's my test, where I add 2 parameters, 'para_1' and 'para_2':

```
@allure.story("测试test_b")
@pytest.mark.parametrize('para', ["para_1", "para_2"])
def test_b(self, para):
    """
    description of test_b
    """
    logging.info("我是test_b的logging: %s" % str(para))
    assert 1 in [0, 1]
```

in this test, I wish to run this test case twice.
But in my test report, I find this case run 3 times:

```
test_b
log: 我是test_b的logging

test_b[para_1]
log: 我是test_b的logging: para_1

test_b[para_2]
log: 我是test_b的logging: para_2
```

Where does the 'test_b' come from? and how can I delete this test?

Answer (score 0):

When I originally write this case, I don't add the parameters, like:

```
@allure.story("测试test_b")
def test_b(self):
    """
    description of test_b
    """
    logging.info("我是test_b的logging")
    assert 1 in [0, 1]
```

and run it.
allure report read the test result data from 'allure-results' folder, where the test_b without parameter test result is kept and not replaced by new test. That's where the test_b from in report.
I can delete both 'allure-results' and 'allure-report' folders to clean the test result data. By this way, original 'test_b' will not be shown.